# Problem installing John the Ripper Jumbo on Kali - libssl-dev dependecy

Tags: debian, package-management, kali-linux, openssl, aptitude

I am trying to install [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) Jumbo on my Kali box. For some reason the version of Kali I recently installed as the host OS on a spare laptop does not seem to have NTLM hash support (whereas another older install I have as a VM does). I get the following message:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/src# ./configure
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking whether to compile using MPI... no
checking for gcc... gcc
...
checking for byte ordering according to target triple... little
checking for OPENSSL... no
configure: error: in `/root/Downloads/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/src':
configure: error: JtR requires OpenSSL and OpenSSL-devel being installed. Install if not installed.
Try using --disable-pkg-config and possibly helping configure find oSSL by providing hints in CFLAGS and LDFLAGS
See `config.log' for more details
```

If I try installing OpenSSL-devel (`libssl-dev` on Debian I beleive) it gives the following:

```
root@kali:~/Downloads/john-1.8.0-jumbo-1/src# aptitude install libssl-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libssl-dev{b} 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  hal libmtp-common poppler-data xpdf 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,593 kB of archives. After unpacking 5,074 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1e-2+deb7u14) but 1.0.1j-1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libssl-dev [Not Installed]                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  hal libmtp-common poppler-data xpdf 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

However, I still have the same problem with `./configure`.

I include the output from `apt-cache` in case this will help.

```
root@kali:~# apt-cache policy libssl-dev libssl1.0.0
libssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.1e-2+deb7u14
  Version table:
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u14 0
        500 http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ kali/updates/main i386 Packages
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u13 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.1j-1
  Candidate: 1.0.1j-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1j-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u14 0
        500 http://security.kali.org/kali-security/ kali/updates/main i386 Packages
     1.0.1e-2+deb7u13 0
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali/ kali/main i386 Packages
```

How can I install OpenSSL-devel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've installed version 1.0.1j-1 of `libssl1.0.0` from somewhere `apt` doesn't know about (hence the lack of a URL in the output of `apt-cache policy`). If you want to install `libssl-dev`, you need to either:

- install the version of `libssl-dev` matching your installed copy of `libssl1.0.0`, from wherever you got `libssl1.0.0`
- downgrade `libssl1.0.0` to match the available version of `libssl-dev` available

To downgrade, answer `n` to `aptitude`'s question, and it should (eventually) suggest downgrading `libssl1.0.0`. Alternatively, you can force the issue by saying

```
aptitude install libssl-dev libssl1.0.0=1.0.1e-2+deb7u14
```

The downgrade shouldn't introduce any security risk, the version available from the security updates is patched.

Answer (score 1):

I faced into the same problem but I solved it by these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

If you rerun the program normally it works.